# Opencart product.tpl not updating

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I really hope someone is able to help as I'm totally losing my mind on this one.

I'm using Opencart Version 2.0.1.0 and for the life of me I can't work out why changes I'm making to `theme/xxx/template/product/product.tpl` is not updating on the live site.

I haven't edited that template in a couple of weeks so not sure if the issue originated today or some time before. All other templates seem to be updating correctly when being edited... just not this one.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be so? I've deleted the cache in both `system/cache` and also `vqmod/vqcache`.

Any help is really appreciated. I've wasted the whole day trying to work this out :(

Comment: Just to add to the above... I've edited the template so that it was just blank and uploaded the template. Still no change on the site but when I delete the template completely it defaults back to the default product.tpl template.

The file is definitely being uploaded to the server correctly.

Comment: It appears it is definitely something to do with the vqcache. The `vq2-system_modification_catalog_view_theme_xxxxx_template_product_product.tpl` that automaticallys gets added to `vqmod/vqcache` is the old version of the template file. Why is it only picking up the old version?

Comment: Sooooo...

I amended the files being used by vqmod where the problem then came back to `system/modification/....../template/template.tpl`

Deleted that file and it finally started using the actual template.tpl file which is now all working correctly.

Is anyone able to advise me on why this happened so that it doesn't happen again?

Comment: OK. Figured it out. After any changes remember to refresh modifications (admin panel --> extentions --> modifictions )

Hopefully this may help someone else who's been tearing their hair out the whole day,

Comment: Thanks for following up on your own question. I had the same problem and refreshing the Modifications page helped

Answer (score 2):

go in modifications and click refresh,after restart page

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [Stack Overflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/about), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score -1):

Put code in this file  `home2/faucetan/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2system_storage_modification_catalog_view_theme_default_template_product_product.tpl`
and also here product.tpl so you see result